# A scrolling List view inside a popup in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my phonegap application for Android, I have a popup contains a `listview`.  This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/de2Lf/3/. The problems are that the scroll didn't appear on the emulator and the back button in the header is not working  correctly.

Why is the scroll not working? What's wrong with my code? Please help me.

```
<div data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       Main Page
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"  >
    <a href="#mypop" data-rel="popup"  id="Btn1"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" >Show    POPUP </a>
    </div>



   <div data-role="popup"  id="mypop" data-position-to="window"  data-corners="false"   data-   overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false"  >

         <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

     <a href=""   id="ClosePOPUP"  data-role="button"  data-icon="custom-close-icon" data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right" ></a>
         <div style="text-align:center;float:center;padding-top:11px;" ><font  size="6px" color="white">pop</font></div>
      </div>

      <div  id="scrollDiv" class="content"  data-role="content"  style="background-color:   white;overflow-y:scroll; ">
             <ul data-role="listview" style="margin: 0 !important;">
                 <li>element</li>
                 <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  <li>element</li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

**java script**

```
      $(document.body).on('click','#ClosePOPUP', function(){ 

        $('#mypop').popup('close');

   });
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated , please help me..

Comment: Is the popup not scrolling or did it just not show the scrollbar?

Comment: Its not showing the scroll bar

Comment: @ whodeee how to make the scrollbar  work on the mobile device? can you help me please?

Comment: If the content is not dynamically loaded the answer I posted should work - if it is dynamic you need to make sure you set a specific height of the listview

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Or the other option is to update your CSS for the listview to have a height 
`height: 90%` or `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: where i should put this line ? sorry for this question but i am new in jQuery mobile

Comment: if you see my jsfiddle i have used  max-height: 550px; but this didnt solve the problem !

Comment: did you add `overflow-y:scroll;` ?

Comment: @   whodeee is there another way to solve this problem since this solution  didn't work for me  ? can you help me more please ?